# Bootstrap nav submenu - multi column right alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, nav

I have created a multi-col submenu in Bootstrap, the submenu is left align with the top level menu, but I need to make it right align with the top menu.

I have tried to use absolute positioning, but no luck. 
Please see the code at http://www.bootply.com/P3fltOTDRF

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item  <b class="caret"></b></a>
            </li> 

            ...
            ...      

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->



.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give `pull-right` to the nav bar?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/Eot2HWSUjT**

Answer (score 1):

What about add class `pull-right` to the `ul` with class `dropdown-menu` like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2 pull-right">
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/dQtw1avQyN)